# Cannot implicitly convert type '(float xpos, int, int)' to 'UnityEngine.Vector3'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, game-engine

I'm new to unity when I try to run this it gives me the error
 Cannot implicitly convert type '(float xpos, int, int)' to 'UnityEngine.Vector3'

This is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField]
private float _speed = 3.5f;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    //variables
    float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    float xpos = transform.position.x ;



    Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontalInput, verticalInput, 0);
    transform.Translate(direction * _speed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (transform.position.y >= 0)
    {
        transform.position = (xpos, 0, 0);
    }
    else if (transform.position.y <= -3.8f)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(xpos, -3.8f, 0);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Look carefully at all of the other lines where you do a similar thing and you'll spot the difference.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I'm sorry, I can't see it.

Comment: `transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);` versus `transform.position = (xpos, 0, 0);`

Comment: Thank you so much! I was pulling my hair out for such a simple fix!

Answer (score 0):

Your missing the constructor on your first `transform.postion`. Should be:

```
transform.position = new Vector3(xpos, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

All right,

Your problem is this statement

**`transform.position = (xpos, 0, 0);`**

Here compiler is excepting an object with exactly the same type as **`transform.position`** at the right side of the assignment operator **(`=`)** which is **`Vector3`**. But when you assign something like a **`float, string`** or something else it gets confused and throws an error, surely if the two types are compatible like **`flot = int`** this won't make any problem. This is what happens here you are introducing compiler to a type of an object which is not defined anywhere nither in compiler nor anywhere in the project. 
Assigning an object to another object there are many ways to do that.

**1). Here I'm creating a new object of `Vector3` by calling its constructor function with `new` keyword.**

`transform.position = new Vector3(xpos, 0, 0)`

**2). Here you already have an object created early in the program and you can change it however you want and then assign.**

```
Vector3 position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
.
.
transform.position = position;
```

**3). And last one you can directly assign oneobject's property to another object**

`transform.position = transform2.position;`